# Setting-up Windows Server 2003 as an L2TP/IPSEC VPN server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I'm looking for a pointer to *step-by-step* instructions for setting-up a Win Server 2003 Std box as a L2TP/IPSEC VPN server. I don't need to use certificates - pre-shared key is sufficient - and the server isn't on a domain.

All the sources of information I've found assume a level of sysadmin experience that I don't have - which is why I'm looking for a step-by-step description. I'm a experienced developer, not an IT person, but I have what I'd guess is intermediate level experience of configuring/administering small-scale servers, and have set-up OpenVPN-based VPNs on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, right from the horse's mouth:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787456(WS.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759171(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something a bit more like "click this, type that, click this..."

Comment: Microsoft links tend to die after each reorganisation of the site (amazing these links still work as of 2018-11). A good SO answer would distil the essential information into the answer

Comment: Seriously. This question and this answer are 9 years old. Let it go.